# PopOver For Annotation View

Tags: ios, storyboard, mapkit, mkannotation, mkannotationview

Well i have a question? Im Confuse!

I have a mapview where the annotations are layed out.Now i want a popover for annotations.

how Should i do it

1.Create a popover controller in storyboard and push it from delgate method.
2.Create a programmatic popover view ,by all sub views and stuff?

I want to use the first method any one help me out.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
```

`{
   // UIViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"annotationPopUp"];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"annotationPush" sender:nil];
}`

Answer (score 3):

In `mapView:didSelectAnnotationView` make your popover (preferably a property) in your class and pressent it. Here's a example:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
    self.popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:yourViewController];

    [self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:view.bounds 
                                  inView:view   
                permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny 
                                animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Think UIPopoverController is only available on iPad

Comment: UIPopoverController is only available on the iPad...But I would use this for iPhone and iPad https://github.com/nicolaschengdev/WYPopoverController